# Adding values from a table to an image band - Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, clustering, table, reclassify

I'm trying to add values from a table to a cluster image. The cluster image has 50 cluster classes, and my table has 50 values for each cluster class. How do I add the values from that table to the image so that each pixel within that cluster class represents that value from the table? I've included an image for clarification.

I understand this might get flagged as too broad, but I've reached the limit of my ability, and I'm in need of some direction. Is something like this even possible in GEE?

Link to my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0d4094a289c9f7f139809b4e9e1f1d05

[image]

Comment: I can't see the table with cluster's values in the code. How do you decide which value goes to the cluster? In the example case you showed, why `new_value` is 0.212 and not -0.212? (last value of the table)

Comment: @ Rodrigo E. Principe  - my bad, I created that pic in paint, didn't change the values. I haven't uploaded the table yet and the values in the pic are for demonstration purposes. Is what I'm proposing possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `remap`. I give you three ways to do it:

1. **Imported Table**

If you want to remap a lot of clusters and you have a table in a local spreadsheet:

- convert it to a csv file
- upload it to a fusion table

```js
// replace `fusion_table_id` to the fusion table id
var table = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:fusion_table_id')

var changeValue = function(feat, image) {
  // cast values
  image = ee.Image(image)
  feat = ee.Feature(feat)

  // get cluster's values
  var cluster = ee.Number(feat.get('cluster'))
  var value = ee.Number(feat.get('value'))

  // remap
  return image.remap([cluster], [value])
}

// iterate over the table
var remapped = ee.Image(table.iterate(changeValue, result))
```

2. **A dictionary of `cluster: value`**

```js
// dict (this is just an example)
var values = ee.Dictionary({
  1: 0.1,
  2: 0.2,
  13: 0.13
})

// as dict's keys are string, you have to parse them as numbers
var keys = values.keys().map(function(key){return ee.Number.parse(key)})

// remap
var remapped = result.remap(keys, values.values())
```

3. **2 lists**

```js
var clusters = [1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   13]
var values =   [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.13]
var remapped = result.remap(clusters, values)
```

Comment: I guess option 2 will answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298796/how-to-reclassify-cluster-image-based-on-values-from-zonal-statistics-google-e